# @ControllerAdvice fails to catch org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am currently working on an api built in java-configured spring 4 that uses a global exception handler to wrap all exceptions thrown on the server into a json object.  I've managed to get this working for every exception I've run into except for the EmptyResultDataAccessException that gets thrown by the jdbcTemplate method queryForObject().  It's currently working for every other exception I can throw at it, but fails on this particular one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Controller Advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    // 400
    @ExceptionHandler(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleEmptyResultDataAccessException(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass()
            .getName());
        final ApiError apiError = new ApiError.Builder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "no results found").build();
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
    }
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass()
            .getName());
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError.Builder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(),
            getAllErrorsFromBindingResult(ex.getBindingResult())).build();
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, apiError, headers, apiError.getStatus(), request);
    }
    //...
    // 500
    @ExceptionHandler({Exception.class, IOException.class, DaoException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAll(final Exception ex, final WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass()
                .getName());
        logger.error("error", ex);

        final ApiError apiError = new ApiError.Builder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getLocalizedMessage(), "error occurred").build();
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(apiError, new HttpHeaders(), apiError.getStatus());
}

    // Helper Methods

    private List<String> getAllErrorsFromBindingResult(BindingResult ex) {
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        ex.getFieldErrors()
                 .forEach(fieldError -> errors.add(fieldError.getField() + ": " + fieldError.getDefaultMessage()));
        ex.getGlobalErrors()
                 .forEach(objectError -> errors.add(objectError.getObjectName() + ": " + objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
        return errors;
    }
}
```

App Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app")
@Import(SwaggerConfig.class)
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:7070");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

App Initializer:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(CeciAppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("ceci-admin-service-dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dynamic.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution for this problem..?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have already figured this out by now. But I noticed in your exception handler class, the method that I ASSUME you were going to use to handle the EmptyResultDataAccessException exceptions, named appropriately handleEmptyResultDataAccessException is actually configured to catch
IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException exceptions based on the annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.class)
```